# A recursive quote/rule about underestimating tasks

Tags: time-management, estimation

There was an interesting quote I read a long time ago that went something like this (It was more like a rule, let's call it the X rule):

The X rule: everyone will underestimate the task assigned to them, even if they are aware of the X rule.

or something like this:

the X rule: A task will always take longer than you think it will take, even if you are aware of the X rule.

Any idea what the exact quote is?

Answer (score 1):

ah got it, it's [Hofstadter's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter%27s_law):

It always takes longer than you expect, even when you take into account Hofstadter's Law.